# What are the tips for answering questions and improving the quality?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality

I have been asking tons of questions on Stack Overflow. I am well, indebted. As times goes by I learn more and more.

I started answering questions. Almost none of my answers are upvoted. I don't even know which questions match my expertise.

What are the tips for answering questions and how to find questions that fit your expertise?

You can check some of my answers. How can I improve those?

Comment: +1 beacuse you like to return answers to the community.

Comment: No upvotes, I don't even know if my answers are seen at all. So I do feel "all the other guys are smarter than I am let them do their things". But hei, if there are tips, I could use some :D.

Comment: For a start; answering old multi-answer questions won't _always_ get _you_ upvotes... you'll be at the bottom of the pile

Comment: Thanks Gamecat, and Ben. Great. Please turn that into an answer.

Comment: @JimThio, although it doesn't look like it from your answers maybe that's your problem. I can't expand a one sentence comment into an answer... I have no need to; it's a comment. You'll get a good, comprehensive, answer shortly you don't need a one liner. (Or this'll be closed as a duplicate as I'm sure it must be but I can't find it)

Comment: As questioners sometimes I feel like I am being too easy on answerers :) After all it's good enough they want to answer in the first place. Maybe I should review that too.

Comment: sadly, one of the most important factors is _being fast_

Comment: I must admit that I can't answer most questions on vb.net either even though I thought I was an expert :(

Answer (score 5):

Top tip:
Look at the answers that did get upvotes. Analyze them. How do they differ from yours? Are they more clearly formulated? Do they contain content you did not include? Are they more in depth? I personally find that by looking at competing answers, I often learn even more and get more out of a question than I have put in.

Or what about the time when they were posted? Was there already a highly upvoted answer, or perhaps multiple answers, which reduce the visibility of yours?

If you're just starting at this whole thing (answering-wise), don't despair. Your reputation might feel like a big rock which is almost impossible to get rolling. But the more you stick to it and the more you learn yourself in the process, the more momentum you will gain. Answering questions is a much a learning experience (or even more so) as asking them is.

With regards to your specific answers:
Your answers are of fairly decent quality, for as far as I can judge them. (Some more knowledgeable on the subjects might even call them good) Though there are quite a few answers for very old questions. Often with highly upvoted and accepted answers. Even if someone were to have a look at those, your contribution might not be immediately visible.

The answers are of course still welcome, but if your goal is rep you might want to focus on newer questions. Follow a couple of your favorite tags and scour them for new questions which you know the answer to. Don't be discouraged if there are multiple immediate answers. Take your time and write a good answer at your own speed. This will ultimately be appreciated. Don't mistake rep, or the lack thereof, as your contributions not being appreciated. Whether it be for answers to old or new questions.

Comment: Wow thanks to say that my questions are "fine". Great. I'll find unanswered questions then :).

Comment: ...answers... ;)

Comment: I wanted to pick this as the answer but I want to wait a while first :) Thanks Bart to take the time to check my answers. I really appreciate that.

Comment: You can decide what you do with acceptance at your own discretion. Feel free to leave this open for other contributions and views. There's no hurry.